# How contexts are represented

Tags: spring

There are 3 main interfaces for **Spring Container(bean factory ,application context and web application context )**.

When we use term "*root/app context and web application context* " then can we say that:

- *web application context* is represented by *web applicationcontext interface* and *servletcontext interface* 
  while
- *root context* is represented by *beanfactory and application context interfaces*.

Answer (score 4):

**BeanFactory** vs **ApplicationContext**

Spring doc explains nicely the about them-

> `ApplicationContext` interface is which enhances `BeanFactory`
>   functionality in a more framework-oriented style

You will have all functionality that a `BeanFactory` can do in `ApplicationCotnext`. Fact is `ApplicationContext` interface extends `ListableBeanFactory` interface. You will find comparative difference between them [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html#context-introduction-ctx-vs-beanfactory)

**ApplicationContext** and **WebApplicationContext**

> `ApplicationContext` is the root context configuration for every web
>   application. But there can be multiple `WebApplicationContext` under
>   the `ApplicationContext`. In other words each `DispatcherServlet` associated with
>   single `WebApplicationContext`.

You can find more [here](http://javabeat.net/spring-mvc-application-context/) for better understanding.

Now can we say - **web application context is represented by web applicationcontext interface and servletcontext interface ?**

Actually `WebApplicationcontext` extended `ApplicationContext` which is designed to work with the standard `ServletContext` so it's able to communicate with the container. like

```
public interface WebApplicationContext extends ApplicationContext {
    ServletContext getServletContext();
}
```

And yes, *root context* or *application context* is represented by `ApplicationContext` interface. And you know the difference of `BeanFactory` with this.

Comment: @Saqib if you think this satisfy your quest, then accept it.